# latest pydev "Invalidate title" memory leak issue?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, memory-leaks, pydev

I can't seem to find a support place for PyDev, so feel free to point me towards it.

When upgrading to the latest PyDev, I get a constantly increasing memory footprint for my window manager if I go into Window -> preferences.  In addition, I when I click on subsections in the preferences window, the right side doesn't refresh.  There is an "Invalidate title" task in the progress tab for eclipse that never seems to end.  I've tried resetting all settings, downgrading eclipse, etc.  Is there a way to grab an older version of PyDev?

PyDev for Eclipse   3.8.0.201409251235
Eclipse 4.4.0 and 4.4.1

I use the C++ CDT install of eclipse and do have the dark style preferences selected (I do recall that PyDev would complain about a lack of a dark stylesheet before).

Answer (score 0):

For PyDev the issue tracker has [moved here](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/). You can report your possible bug over there.
As for general support, you have chosen the right palce to come. The PyDev [forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/discussion/) title asks everyone to go to Stackoverflow and ask with PyDev tag. 
The "Invalidate Title" task seems to be [meant to always run](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8169680/). It checks for duplicate editor names.
If you are looking for older PyDev versions, you can download them [at the sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/)